Expose a getter as a simple variable name, 'detached' from parent object (without using a `with` statement)
Note: This question is not about 'regular' JavaScript, or best practices. It's about "hacking" the JavaScript language as part of a DSL. I'm working on an update to the DSL which is backwards-compatible with the previous approach, so I need to faithfully match all the existing behavior. Please interpret this question in that light.

Question:
Let's say we have an object with a getter like this:
let obj = {
  get foo() {
    console.log('executed');
    return 1;
  }
};

And our task is to somehow "pull foo out of obj" so that instead of writing obj.foo we can just write foo.
This is possible using a with statement:
<script>
  with(obj) {
    // example of user-land code, which I have no control over:
    console.log(foo + 1); // logs 'executed' and then '2'
    let bar = 3; // `bar` is trapped inside the `with` block, which is the thing I'm trying to avoid
  }
</script>

However, this creates a block scope, which I want to avoid because it traps variable declarations like let bar = 3; inside the block scope.
Important: I have full control over the construction of the above code. I'm simply given the user-land code (like the above 2 lines) as a string, and I can do whatever I want with it, so long as I expose the obj getters, and ensure that top-level declarations like let bar = 3 aren't "trapped". The existing solution involves 'parsing' the user code for top-level declarations, and pulling them out of the with 'manually', but I'd like to get rid of the with statement.
Thoughts:
I'm fairly sure this is not possible without something quite heavy-handed (e.g. runtime AST parsing stuff). This ability for with to expose a getter as a 'direct' variable name seems unique. I figured I'd ask just in case there's a god-tier JS dev here who knows some dark magic that I don't.
I don't think Proxy is useful here, since there is no handler for simple 'references' to the Proxy object itself - only properties of it, or function calls on it, etc.
I'm not sure how relevant it will be to this question, since I don't understand many of the details, but:
13.11 With Statement:

The with statement adds an object Environment Record for a computed object to the lexical environment of the running execution context. It then executes a statement using this augmented lexical environment. Finally, it restores the original lexical environment.

8.1.1 Environment Records:

There are two primary kinds of Environment Record values used in this specification: declarative Environment Records and object Environment Records. Declarative Environment Records are used to define the effect of ECMAScript language syntactic elements such as FunctionDeclarations, VariableDeclarations, and Catch clauses that directly associate identifier bindings with ECMAScript language values. Object Environment Records are used to define the effect of ECMAScript elements such as WithStatement that associate identifier bindings with the properties of some object. Global Environment Records and function Environment Records are specializations that are used for specifically for Script global declarations and for top-level declarations within functions.

The only alternative pathway available to me here is to come up with a robust way to "export"

In other words, you want foo to invoke a function without writing foo(). That should not be desirable, as it introduces unexpected "magic" into the code and easily leads to bugs. Perhaps it'd be possible in a limited fashion by defining window.foo as a getter, but that's getting really yucky.

@deceze Please read the notice that I very deliberately added to the top of the question! :) I added it when writing the question to specifically avoid misunderstandings (of the question's requirements) like the one in your comment.

I believe that note didn't exist when I wrote that comment? Anyway, your DSL is basically Javascript except for that one detail? You want to evaluate it using the Javascript runtime?

@deceze It did! It was in the very first version, but perhaps it's a bit easy to miss due to the big 'Question' header with the <hr> above it, which may guide the eye past it. And yep, the DSL is based on JavaScript, though it adds a bunch of extra things - not just the feature related to this question.

You could do this by looping through all your getters in an object and creating a function attached to the global window object. That would let you call your getters as stand-alone functions.
Say you've got your example object:
    let obj = {
      get foo() {
        console.log('executed');
        return 1;
      }
      get 
    };

To hoist your getter as a function:
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key);
      if (descriptor && typeof descriptor.get === 'function') {
        window[key] = descriptor.get.bind(null);
      }
    }

The above loops through all your object props, checks if the prop is a function, and then hoists it to the global scope.
You can then call your 'getter' with:
    foo() // output: executed, 1


Unfortunately I don't control the code inside the current with block. As mentioned, it's "userland" code which relies on the previous behavior: "I'm working on an update to the DSL which is backwards-compatible with the previous approach, so I need to faithfully match all the existing behavior." Either way, thank you for the attempt! I'll admit these are some tough requirements - I wouldn't be surprised if what I'm trying to achieve is simply not possible.
